# Instantiating Viewmodel with Activity in constructor with Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, dependency-injection, viewmodel

all. 
I have one viewmodel I want to be shared between all the fragments and the activity they exist on. The issue is, the viewmodel needs reference to the activity for the construction of the Database that is attached to it. And I am using Dagger2 to inject the dependency, rather than instantiate them.

What can I do to go about this? 
I tried adding bundles with the reference, that didn't work. I tried launching the first fragment with the navcontroller, but that didn't work either, as I can't pass the activity reference in the arguments. 
I can't pass the reference through the shared viewmodel, because I am unable to instantiate it without the reference. So I am completely lost.

```
class HooskBankBranchesFragment(private val activity: AccountDetailsActivity) : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: AccountsProfileViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.hoosk_bank_branches_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        DaggerAccountsProfileComponent.builder()
            .accountsProfileModule(AccountsProfileModule(activity))
            .appComponent((activity?.application as HooskApp).component())
            .build().inject(this)


        rv_bankAccounts.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        viewModel.state.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            when(it){
                is AccountsProfileViewModelState.OnDatabaseAccountsFetched -> rv_bankAccounts.adapter = BankDetailsRvAdapter(it.bankAccounts)
                is AccountsProfileViewModelState.Error -> Toast.makeText(activity, it.throwable.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        viewModel.getAccounts()


    }
}
```

This is the Fragment class which will isn't able to be created because I can't pass the reference of the activity using NavController.

```
class AccountsProfileViewModel(private val repository: AccountProfileRepository) : ViewModel() {


    private val _state = MutableLiveData<AccountsProfileViewModelState>()

    val state: LiveData<AccountsProfileViewModelState>
        get() = _state

    fun getAccounts() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _state.value = AccountsProfileViewModelState.OnDatabaseAccountsFetched(repository.getAccounts())
            } catch (error: Throwable) {
                _state.value = AccountsProfileViewModelState.Error(error)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getOnlineAccounts(accessCode: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _state.value = AccountsProfileViewModelState.OnOnlineAccountFetched(repository.getOnlineAccounts("Bearer $accessCode"))
            } catch (error: Throwable) {
                _state.value = AccountsProfileViewModelState.Error(error)
            }
        }
    }

    fun addAccount(account: BankAccountAPIModel) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                repository.addAccount(account)
            } catch (error: Throwable) {
                _state.value = AccountsProfileViewModelState.Error(error)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getAccount(url: String){
        val sanitizer = UrlQuerySanitizer(url)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val accessToken = repository.getAccessCode(sanitizer.getValue("code"))
                val onlineAccount = repository.getOnlineAccounts("Bearer " + accessToken.accessToken)
                _state.value = AccountsProfileViewModelState.OnOnlineAccountFetched(onlineAccount)

                repository.addAccount(onlineAccount)
                _state.value = AccountsProfileViewModelState.OnDatabaseAccountsFetched(repository.getAccounts())

            }catch (error: Throwable){
                _state.value = AccountsProfileViewModelState.Error(error)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getAccessCode(url: String) {
        val sanitizer = UrlQuerySanitizer(url)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _state.value = AccountsProfileViewModelState.OnAccessTokenRetrieved(repository.getAccessCode(sanitizer.getValue("code")))
            } catch (error: Throwable) {
                _state.value = AccountsProfileViewModelState.Error(error)
            }
        }
    }


}



sealed class AccountsProfileViewModelState{
    object Loading : AccountsProfileViewModelState()
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable): AccountsProfileViewModelState()
    data class OnAccessTokenRetrieved(val accessToken: AccessToken): AccountsProfileViewModelState()
    data class OnOnlineAccountFetched(val bankAccount: BankAccountAPIModel): AccountsProfileViewModelState()
    data class OnDatabaseAccountsFetched(val bankAccounts: List<BankAccountAPIModel>): AccountsProfileViewModelState()
}
```

Here is my ViewModel, I'm not sure if that helps anything.

What I did manage to do, which I realised promptly was incorrect, was creating the viewmodel twice, one attached to the activity, and one to the fragment. Which only updated the fragment from the database once I restarted the app. I realised that's when it was wrong, as I wasn't able to observe the exact viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue.

```
        DaggerAccountsProfileComponent.builder()
            .accountsProfileModule(AccountsProfileModule(activity))
            .appComponent((activity?.application as HooskApp).component())
            .build().inject(this)
```

I removed the reference in the constructor and changed the AccountsProfileModule(activity) to:

````
        DaggerAccountsProfileComponent.builder()
            .accountsProfileModule(AccountsProfileModule(activity as AccountDetailsActivity))
            .appComponent((activity?.application as HooskApp).component())
            .build().inject(this)
```
````